# URL Schema for App Store update view controller

Tags: ios, app-store, url-scheme

Is there a URL Schema for just opening the App Store on an iOS device, or the App Store's update view controller? I've searched through the internet and find many examples that open to a specific application, but that is not what we need.  We just need to open up the App Store application.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the App Store through `itms-apps://`, but it only seems to work if the App Store has recently been used.